# Partially download and serialize big file in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, download

As part of an upcoming project at my university, I need to write a client that downloads a media file from a server and writes it to the local disk. Since these files can be very large, I need to implement partial download and serialization in order to avoid excessive memory use.

What I came up with:

```
namespace PartialDownloadTester
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;

    public class DownloadClient
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dlc = new DownloadClient(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
            dlc.DownloadAndSaveToDisk();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private WebRequest request;

        // directory of file
        private string dir;

        // full file identifier
        private string filePath;

        public DownloadClient(string uri, string fileName, string fileType)
        {
            this.request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            this.request.Method = "GET";
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("C:\\testdata\\DownloadedData\\");
            this.dir = sb.ToString();
            sb.Append(fileName + "." + fileType);
            this.filePath = sb.ToString();
        }

        public void DownloadAndSaveToDisk()
        {
            // make sure directory exists
            this.CreateDir();

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Content length: " + response.ContentLength);
            var rStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            int bytesRead = -1;
            do
            {
                var buf = new byte[2048];
                bytesRead = rStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                rStream.Flush();
                this.SerializeFileChunk(buf);
            }
            while (bytesRead != 0);
        }

        private void CreateDir()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }
        }

        private void SerializeFileChunk(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Contract.Requires(!Object.ReferenceEquals(bytes, null));
            FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I've used the following parameters:

> "http://itu.dk/people/janv/mufc_abc.jpg" "mufc_abc" "jpg"

However, the picture is incomplete (only the first ~10% look right) even though the content length prints 63780 which is the actual size of the image.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is this the right way to go for partial download and serialization or is there a better/easier approach?
2. Is the full content of the response stream stored in client memory? If this is the case, do I need to use HttpWebRequest.AddRange to partially download data from the server in order to conserve my client's memory?
3. How come the serialization fails and I get a broken image?
4. Do I introduce a lot of overhead when I use the FileMode.Append? (msdn states that this option "seeks to the end of the file")

Thanks in advance

Comment: any solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the source of the problem, however I would change the loop like this

```
const int ChunkSize = 2048;
var buf = new byte[ChunkSize];
var rStream = response.GetResponseStream();
do {
    int bytesRead = rStream.Read(buf, 0, ChunkSize);
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        this.SerializeFileChunk(buf, bytesRead);
    }
} while (bytesRead == ChunkSize);
```

The serialize method would get an additional argument

```
private void SerializeFileChunk(byte[] bytes, int numBytes)
```

and then write the right number of bytes

```
fs.Write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
```

---

UPDATE:

I do not see the need for closing and reopening the file each time. I also would use the `using` statement, which closes the resources, even if an exception should occur. The `using` statement calls the `Dispose()` method of the resource at the end, which in turn calls `Close()` in the case of file streams. `using` can be applied to all types implementing `IDisposable`.

```
var buf = new byte[2048];
using (var rStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append)) {
        do {
            bytesRead = rStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (...);
    }
}
```

The using statement does something like this

```
{
    var rStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    try
    {
        // do some work with rStream here.
    } finally {
        if (rStream != null) {
            rStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right; I do need to pass readBytes as argument to SerializeFileChunk so I can fix fs.Write call to work on readBytes rather than the length of the byte array. Thank you!
(Edit: The loop did not necessarily need your proposed changes after introducing the second argument for SerializeFileChunk)

Comment: I added some explanations and placed the byte buffer creation before the loop, since there is no point in creating a new buffer at each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

You could definitely simplify your code using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DownloadClient("http://itu.dk/people/janv/mufc_abc.jpg", "mufc_abc.jpg");
    }

    public static void DownloadClient(string uri, string fileName)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(uri))
            {
                // work with chunks of 2KB => adjust if necessary
                const int chunkSize = 2048;
                var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                using (var output = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                {
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I am writing only the number of bytes I have actually read from the socket to the output file and not the entire 2KB buffer.

Comment: Why don't you use simply `client.DownloadFile`

Comment: @L.B presumably the professor wants them to learn about and understand stream handling.

Comment: Maybe the professor wants them to use `Range` header (in Q: `I need to implement partial download`)

Comment: Thank you, I did not have knowledge of the WebClient class - it looks very handy. I think you are right that the damaged image problem is caused by the fact that I write the entire buffer.
@L.B: msdn does not state how this is implemented. It does indeed partially download and write the file?
(I do not have to use streams. I chose to use streams since that is how I've learned to do data transfer so far.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406

Updated 2021-03-16: seems the original article is not available now. Here is the archived one: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/812406

Comment: page not found.