# Downloading image from url doesn't always save the entire image (Winrt)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I'm using the following code to download an image from a url

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri("<your url>"));
        var file = await KnownFolders.PictureLibrary.CreateFileAsync("myfile.png");
        using (var targetStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (stream)
                await stream.CopyToAsync(targetStream.AsStreamForWrite());
        }
```

several users have reported that it doesn't always download the entire image.  That they sometimes get partial images and the rest is just garbage.

Is there any reason for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to flush/close/dispose the target stream/file?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I assumed that the using block would take care of that for me.  But I'll give that a try.  Unfortunately I can't recreate the issue so any "fix" I put in will be blind.  
Just realized the stream is NOT in a using block

Comment: @Javalsu what does the documentation say about the Dispose method on stream that gets returned from Client.GetStreamAsync. Some streams need to be flushed and others don't

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365687/partially-download-and-serialize-big-file-in-c

Comment: I guess it is because you are calling GetStreamAsync().........You need to make a Synchronus call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958829/how-do-i-use-the-new-httpclient-from-windows-web-http-to-download-an-image/41507504#41507504

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest trying the WebClient class with the DownloadData or DownloadDataAsync method.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.png",
    new WebClient().DownloadData("<your url>"));
```

**edit** If the stream is giving you trouble you could use the byte array response instead. Your  "using" statement with async code inside may be causing it to dispose early, perhaps?

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var data = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri("<Your URI>"));
var file = await KnownFolders.PictureLibrary.CreateFileAsync("myfile.png");
var targetStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
await targetStream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
targetStream.FlushAsync().Wait();
targetStream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't believe this works in Winrrt.

Comment: @Javalsu - I think the issue is probably with the "using" statement disposing the object too early or a stream/completion issue with HttpClient. I edited my answer to reflect a "possibly" more stable solution for you.

Answer (score 3):

BackgroundDownloader is the easiest way to download a file.

```
using Windows.Storage;

public async Task DownloadPhoto(Uri uri)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var photoFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var downloader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader();
    var dl = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, photoFile);
    await dl.StartAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately I have tried this method and it didn't work out for me.  My app has a lot of processes that run in the background and it appears that this method has to wait for all the other processes to end before it can start.  So I wasn't able to use it.

Comment: Even with an await at StartAsync() and an await at download function ?

Comment: Yes, it was very confusing, it would hit the await line and never progress.  I started a discussion on the microsoft forum and the consensus what that I had other processes that were blocking it from starting.

I couldn't confirm that that was the true cause, but nothing that was suggested would get it working.

Comment: Yeah, it happened to me too :/
It was when I was using asynchronous methods in synchronous one.
Like call awaitable functions with .Result.
I fix the problem with using only asynchronous...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look in to that.

Answer (score 1):

If your using HttpClient then if your image is larger than 64K it will error out. You will have to set the httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize to something larger.

See the MSDN Quick Start where they set the max-buffer-size to 256K.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ152726(v=win.10).aspx

Personally though, I use the BackgroundDownloader.