# Download and save a picture from a url Universal windows app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using the below code to downlaod the picture form a remote url and save to Local storage folder

```
        try
        {
            var rootFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync( "MyAppName\\CoverPics", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            var coverpic_file = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
            try
            {
                var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(coverUrl);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using (var stream = await coverpic_file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await resStream.CopyToAsync(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
                }
                response.Dispose();
            }
            catch //any exceptions happend while saving the picture
            {
                saved = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227250.aspx 
            //Raise an exception if file already present 
            saved = true;
        }
```

This code is working for me in most of the cases , but i noticed that for few pictures the image is not downloading completely.

I am callling this function in an async block for more tahn 100 images in a single go inside the foreach loop and in the end few of them are failed downloads

[ Either i can see some invalid file is getting created

or part of image only in downloading and rest of the area i can see a black colour block [ looks like image is corrupted].

Size of all images is less than 1 MB only

Can some one help me to optimize this code or point out the mistake in code so i can able to download all the images completely

Comment: Your code looks ok -_-

Comment: Any idea why the images are not downloading completely then ? Is any impact of memory limitations? DO i need to read response as bytes of data ? Or any improvements is possible on this code?

Comment: @kiewic Can you please see answer posted and any comments on that?

Comment: This has worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958829/how-do-i-use-the-new-httpclient-from-windows-web-http-to-download-an-image/41507504#41507504

Answer (score 6):

I am not seeing any error in my code. But after trying some different ways of downloading and saving a file my code looks like this and

```
 try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // Create HttpClient
                byte[] buffer = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(coverUrl); // Download file
                using (Stream stream = await coverpic_file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Save
            }
            catch
            {
                saved = false;
            }
```

And this code is working fine without causing any issues All images are downloading completely and no more issues of black block on images.

If any one can points out the difference with my first code will be really helpful to understood the reason for error

Comment: You now using HttpClient instead HttpWebRequest .

Comment: YES . And with this piece of code my issue solved .But still i want to know whats the impact of HttpClient over WebRequest If some one can explain

Comment: I don't know what `HttpClient` do internally, but have you check video in CH9 link I provided in my answer ? They explain why should use it over the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using new `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`?

Also take a look this SO question : 
[How do I use the new HttpClient from Windows.Web.Http to download an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958829/how-do-i-use-the-new-httpclient-from-windows-web-http-to-download-an-image)

If you not familiar with `HttpClient`, I sugest to watch CH9 presentation :
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-092

Comment: I checked it and seen that in the thread they are converting to a BitmapImage  and i am trying to save stream to file . I think its problem with read as chunks so nothing will lose while saving image. Any helps will be appreciable for doing this. Still i am struggling

Comment: Are you download images simultaneously ? Or one image at time ?

Comment: One at a time and even if it not exists

Comment: NO All my downloads are OK no exceptions i am getting . Only thing is that  very few images looks like damaged [part of image only is perfect]

Answer (score 0):

I tried your download and experienced the same issues.

```
var myFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyFolderPath", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(URL), myFile);
await download.StartAsync();
```