# uwp unable to save file

Tags: c#, file, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm trying to save a file to the application storage using these methods (when the app is running):

First I create the file from an URI:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(name, uri, RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri));
```

Then I copy the file to the app's storage to be able to use it later:

```
StorageFile file2 = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

But the second method *CopyAsync()* does not finish and then randomly fails with this error after waiting ~5min:

[image: Error screenshot].

Also, processes are added in the app's lifecycle every time I call t he *CopyAsync()* method:

[image: Lifecycle processes].

When I click on one of the processes, the *CopyAsync()* method ends.

To solve this issue I have to reboot my phone and uninstall/install the app.

NOTE: When I try this in a background task this fail 100% of the time.

Comment: The full project is located at [my github repo](https://github.com/rootasjey/citations365)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603849/download-and-save-a-picture-from-a-url-universal-windows-app)

And the code works in a background task as well :)

This does not explain why the *FileStorage.CopyAsync()* method fails, but it's a workaround until someone gets more information.

*(It seems when CopyAsync() fails in a background task it will block any futur call to this method in a background task or in the foreground app)*

The code snippet:

```
 private async Task<StorageFile> DownloadImagefromServer(string URI, string filename) {
        filename += ".png";
        var rootFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Citations365\\CoverPics", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var coverpic = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            byte[] buffer = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URI); // Download file
            using (Stream stream = await coverpic.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Save

            return coverpic;
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
 }
```