# c# Dropbox RestSharp download part of file

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api, restsharp

I have an 'ASP.NET' console application, i use the 'RestSharp' client for Dropbox.
I need to download part of file from Dropbox (fro example i need to read from 0 byte to 10000 byte) and should not download all file.

I need to send the bytes in request and not get the whole file or save the whole file in local storage or in memory.

Comment: hope this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365687/partially-download-and-serialize-big-file-in-c

Comment: Thanks @Jelly for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`/files (GET)` in Dropbox API v1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files-GET) supports HTTP range retrieval requests, so for your example, you can just add the header `Range: bytes=0-10001` to your API call.

(I believe that API v2 support for range retrieval is planned but not yet implemented.)

Comment: Thanks @smarx for answer.